# React passwordless login with firebase: Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to enable passwordless login with React and I'm running into an error.
[image: Google Firebase Auth Setup]

firebase.ts

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 'XXXXX',
    authDomain: 'XXXX',
    projectId: 'XX',
    storageBucket: 'XX',
    messagingSenderId: 'XX',
    appId: 'XXX',
}

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

export const auth = getAuth(app)
export default app
```

When I try to use any of these functions the code works just fine.

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword,signInWithEmailAndPassword
```

For example, this works fine ->

```
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, sendEmailVerification } from 'firebase/auth'
import { TextInput, Button, Box } from '@mantine/core'
import { useForm } from '@mantine/form'
import { auth } from '../../firebase/firebase'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import passwordAndEmailFormValidation from '../utils/formValidation'

export default function SignUp() {
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const form = useForm(passwordAndEmailFormValidation)

    const handleSignUp = async () => {
        form.validate()
        const { email, password } = form.values
        console.log(email, password)
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then(userCredential => {
                const user = userCredential.user
                console.log(user)
                sendEmailVerification(user)
                navigate('/verify-email')
            })
            .catch(error => {
                const errorCode = error.code
                const errorMessage = error.message
                console.log({ errorCode, errorMessage })
            })
    }

    return (
        <Box p="3rem">
            Sign Up
            <Box w="400px">
                <TextInput
                    withAsterisk
                    label="Email"
                    placeholder="your@email.com"
                    size="sm"
                    type="email"
                    {...form.getInputProps('email')}
                />
                <TextInput
                    withAsterisk
                    type="password"
                    label="Password"
                    size="sm"
                    placeholder="password"
                    {...form.getInputProps('password')}
                />
                <Box mt="1rem">
                    <Button onClick={handleSignUp}>Submit</Button>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    )
}
```

However, whenever I replace createUserWithEmailAndPassword to sendSignInLinkToEmail  I get the error message *Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error).*

```
sendSignInLinkToEmail(auth, email, {url:"http://localhost:3000"}).then(()=>{

    console.log("Email sent")
})
```

Any suggestions on how I could fix this? Been stuck on this for a while so any help would be appreciated. Using Firebase v9 on React 18.

Comment: Could you put a .catch in the promise to get more details about the error?

Comment: It's the same error message so didn't help.

Comment: In the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Error#common-error-codes) we can see that there is some wrong argument, but just by this block of code I can't identify the error.

Comment: I've added more code now, including the config and a full example of how I'm using it

Comment: Try using json in the link settings.
```{
   "url":"http://localhost:3000",
   "handleCodeInApp": true
 }```